# What is autoload?

Tags: latex-base

In the LaTeX kernel you see this often:

```
%<*2ekernel|autoload>
```

What does it do? There are other similar marks. Is there any documentation for these?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When LaTeX2e was released, personal computers had much less power than nowadays. Moreover, TeX was often compiled with a rather small amount of available memory.

The inclusion of the New Font Selection Scheme (NFSS2), in particular, posed some challenges when LaTeXing big documents. So the developers provided a solution for people with limited memory available: if the autoload option was set during the extraction of `latex.ltx` from the sources, not all the kernel was included in the format which was then produced by running `initex` on this file: some parts of it were included "on demand", for instance the code for the `picture` environment.

Support of the `autoload` feature was introduced in the June 1995 release of the LaTeX kernel update and dropped in December 2003.

You can still find a description of this feature in the file

```
<TEX DIST ROOT>/doc/latex/base/autoload.txt
```

> On some small systems (perhaps most noticeably emTeX for PCs if your
>   machine is unable to use the TeX386 version) LaTeX uses up a large
>   amount of the memory available to TeX, leaving very little for storage
>   of any further commands, complex text (such as tables), floats or
>   cross references that may occur in a typical document.  Note that
>   these limits are built into the TeX executable and do not directly
>   correspond to any physical memory that your machine has installed.
>
> In order to help with this problem, we have produced an *experimental*
>   configuration of LaTeX in which certain functions are not predefined
>   in the format, but are loaded automatically from a style file the first
>   time they are used.  This saves a lot of memory in the case that a
>   document does not use these features.
>
> In this release two environments are ‘auto-loaded’ in this way,
>   ‘picture’ and ‘tabbing’, as are various bits of internal code used in
>   error handling, font loading and advanced page makeup.

Comment: You just beat me to it :-)

Comment: @JosephWright I was using LaTeX at that time and was actually bitten by memory shortage. But happily a version of OzTeX was released that could be easily assigned more memory.

Answer (score 8):

The kernel files are written using the special kind of literate programming: LaTeX `dtx` system.  Each `dtx` file is both documentation and code.  `docstrip` program  extracts the code and rearranges it into latex files.  The "guards" inside `<` and `>` tell `docstrip` where the snippets belong.  For example, `<*2ekernel|autoload>` says that the code belongs to the files `latex.ltx` *and* `latexa.ltx`

Saying `texdoc docstrip` will give you more details about these "guards".

Comment: You say ...`latex.ltx` and `latexa.ltx` How does `docstrip` know it is not `latexb.ltx`?

Comment: it is in the file `autoload.ins`, which is a `docstrip` program